Using xTaskCreate to run a function, but code after task is created will not run
I am creating a project using an esp32 that will simulate traffic lights. I have two traffic lights wired up, and when one has a red light, the other is green. A light is supposed to stay green for 10 seconds, then turn red, and then the other light will turn green. In this project, I am supposed to have it set to listen for a button press, and if pressed the light will stay green for 20 seconds. I made a function called buttonCheck to check if the button is pressed. I use xTaskCreate to have it check for the button press while the lights run, but the code after the task does not work when I create the task.
ButtonCheck function:
void buttonCheck(void *parameters){
    int *timer = (int *)parameters;
    esp_rom_gpio_pad_select_gpio(GPIO_NUM_0);
    gpio_set_direction(GPIO_NUM_0, GPIO_MODE_INPUT);
    gpio_set_pull_mode(GPIO_NUM_0, GPIO_PULLUP_ONLY);
    bool timeswitch = true;
    vTaskDelay(500/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    while(1){
        if(gpio_get_level(GPIO_NUM_0) == 0 && timeswitch){
            *timer = 2000;
            timeswitch = false;
            // vTaskDelay(500/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        }

        if(gpio_get_level(GPIO_NUM_0) == 0 && !timeswitch){
            *timer = 10000;
            timeswitch = true;
            // vTaskDelay(500/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        }
        //  vTaskDelay(10000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}

How I call the function in main and the code that follows
xTaskCreate(buttonCheck, "BUTTONPRESSCHECK", 150, &timer, 14, NULL);

while (1) {
    if (EWgreen) {
        toRed(EWlight);
        vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        toGreen(NSlight);
        EWgreen = false;
    }
    else {
        toRed(NSlight);
        vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        toGreen(EWlight);
        EWgreen = true;
    }
    vTaskDelay(timer / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
}

The function does work, and the task executes. I am new to embedded applications so after doing some research I tried decreasing/increasing the stack size and lowering the priority of the function. Those did not change the result. I thought to insert a taskDelay before the function enters the while loop, in hopes this would give the controller more time to reach the code after I create the task. This also did not change the result. Any Help would be appreciated!
Here is all the code:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<freertos/FreeRTOS.h>
#include<freertos/task.h>
#include<driver/gpio.h>

struct ledstuff {

    gpio_num_t red;
    gpio_num_t yellow;
    gpio_num_t green;

};

typedef struct ledstuff ledinfo;

void
toRed(ledinfo data)
{

    gpio_set_level(data.green, 0);
    gpio_set_level(data.yellow, 1);
    vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    gpio_set_level(data.yellow, 0);
    gpio_set_level(data.red, 1);

}

void
toGreen(ledinfo data)
{

    gpio_set_level(data.red, 0);
    gpio_set_level(data.yellow, 0);
    gpio_set_level(data.green, 1);

}

void
trafficLights(void *params)
{

    int *timer = (int *) params;
    bool EWgreen = true;
    ledinfo NSlight;

    NSlight.red = GPIO_NUM_19;
    NSlight.yellow = GPIO_NUM_18;
    NSlight.green = GPIO_NUM_5;
    ledinfo EWlight;

    EWlight.red = GPIO_NUM_27;
    EWlight.yellow = GPIO_NUM_26;
    EWlight.green = GPIO_NUM_25;

    gpio_set_level(NSlight.red, 1);
    gpio_set_level(EWlight.green, 1);
    vTaskDelay(3000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    while (1) {

        if (EWgreen) {
            toRed(EWlight);
            vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            toGreen(NSlight);
            EWgreen = false;
        }
        else {
            toRed(NSlight);
            vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            toGreen(EWlight);
            EWgreen = true;
        }
        vTaskDelay(*timer / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

    }

}

void
buttonCheck(void *parameters)
{

    int *timer = (int *) parameters;

    esp_rom_gpio_pad_select_gpio(GPIO_NUM_0);
    gpio_set_direction(GPIO_NUM_0, GPIO_MODE_INPUT);
    gpio_set_pull_mode(GPIO_NUM_0, GPIO_PULLUP_ONLY);
    bool timeswitch = true;

    vTaskDelay(500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

    while (1) {

        if (gpio_get_level(GPIO_NUM_0) == 0 && timeswitch) {
            *timer = 2000;
            gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_18, 1);
            timeswitch = false;
            // vTaskDelay(500/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        }

        if (gpio_get_level(GPIO_NUM_0) == 0 && !timeswitch) {
            *timer = 10000;
            gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_18, 0);
            timeswitch = true;
            // vTaskDelay(500/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        }
        // vTaskDelay(10000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

    }

}

void
app_main()
{

    int timer = 10000;
    bool EWgreen = true;

    gpio_set_direction(18, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(19, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(5, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);

    gpio_set_direction(27, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(26, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(25, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);

    ledinfo NSlight;

    NSlight.red = GPIO_NUM_19;
    NSlight.yellow = GPIO_NUM_18;
    NSlight.green = GPIO_NUM_5;
    ledinfo EWlight;

    EWlight.red = GPIO_NUM_27;
    EWlight.yellow = GPIO_NUM_26;
    EWlight.green = GPIO_NUM_25;

    gpio_set_level(NSlight.red, 1);
    gpio_set_level(EWlight.green, 1);
    vTaskDelay(3000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    xTaskCreate(buttonCheck, "BUTTONPRESSCHECK", 150, &timer, 14, NULL);
// xTaskCreate(trafficLights,"TRAFFICLIGHTS",400,&timer,5,NULL);

    while (1) {

        if (EWgreen) {

            toRed(EWlight);
            vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            toGreen(NSlight);
            EWgreen = false;

        }
        else {

            toRed(NSlight);
            vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            toGreen(EWlight);
            EWgreen = true;

        }

        vTaskDelay(timer / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

    }
}


I believe your current code will be small enough. Please post all of it. In particular, we'd like to see all initialization related calls and the call to vTaskStartScheduler, etc.

Note that if you have code in your main function that comes after the call to vTaskStartScheduler, that code will never be executed.

@CraigEstey I wasn't using vTaskStartScheduler, because it seemed like I wasn't using it correctly. But in the example I was shown, it seemed like it wasn't needed. Is it something I 100% need?

@RyanPerez yes, as it starts freeRTOS. Without it you do not have it.

Prefaced by the top comments ...

Is it something I 100% need? –
Ryan Perez

Yes ...

Unlike posix [linux] threads (with (e.g.) pthread_create), under freertos, xTaskCreate will not start the task.
This must be done by calling vTaskStartScheduler from the main function.
Any code that follows this call will not be executed.
Any such "main task" code must be put into its own task (e.g. main_task below)


Here is the refactored code. I edited it, but it is not compiled nor tested:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <freertos/FreeRTOS.h>
#include <freertos/task.h>
#include <driver/gpio.h>

struct ledstuff {
    gpio_num_t red;
    gpio_num_t yellow;
    gpio_num_t green;
};

typedef struct ledstuff ledinfo;

void
toRed(ledinfo data)
{

    gpio_set_level(data.green, 0);
    gpio_set_level(data.yellow, 1);
    vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    gpio_set_level(data.yellow, 0);
    gpio_set_level(data.red, 1);
}

void
toGreen(ledinfo data)
{

    gpio_set_level(data.red, 0);
    gpio_set_level(data.yellow, 0);
    gpio_set_level(data.green, 1);
}

void
trafficLights(void *params)
{
    int *timer = (int *) params;
    bool EWgreen = true;
    ledinfo NSlight;

    NSlight.red = GPIO_NUM_19;
    NSlight.yellow = GPIO_NUM_18;
    NSlight.green = GPIO_NUM_5;
    ledinfo EWlight;

    EWlight.red = GPIO_NUM_27;
    EWlight.yellow = GPIO_NUM_26;
    EWlight.green = GPIO_NUM_25;

    gpio_set_level(NSlight.red, 1);
    gpio_set_level(EWlight.green, 1);

    vTaskDelay(3000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

    while (1) {
        if (EWgreen) {
            toRed(EWlight);
            vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            toGreen(NSlight);
            EWgreen = false;
        }

        else {
            toRed(NSlight);
            vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            toGreen(EWlight);
            EWgreen = true;
        }

        vTaskDelay(*timer / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }

}

void
buttonCheck(void *parameters)
{
    int *timer = (int *) parameters;

    esp_rom_gpio_pad_select_gpio(GPIO_NUM_0);
    gpio_set_direction(GPIO_NUM_0, GPIO_MODE_INPUT);
    gpio_set_pull_mode(GPIO_NUM_0, GPIO_PULLUP_ONLY);
    bool timeswitch = true;

    vTaskDelay(500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

    while (1) {
        if (gpio_get_level(GPIO_NUM_0) == 0 && timeswitch) {
            *timer = 2000;
            gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_18, 1);
            timeswitch = false;
            // vTaskDelay(500/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        }

        if (gpio_get_level(GPIO_NUM_0) == 0 && !timeswitch) {
            *timer = 10000;
            gpio_set_level(GPIO_NUM_18, 0);
            timeswitch = true;
            // vTaskDelay(500/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        }

        // vTaskDelay(10000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}

#if 1
// NOTE/FIX: main code must be in its own task
void
main_task(void *vp)
{
    int *timer = vp;
    bool EWgreen = true;

    while (1) {
        if (EWgreen) {
            toRed(EWlight);
            vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            toGreen(NSlight);
            EWgreen = false;
        }

        else {
            toRed(NSlight);
            vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            toGreen(EWlight);
            EWgreen = true;
        }

        vTaskDelay(*timer / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}
#endif

void
app_main()
{

// NOTE/BUG(?) -- timer on the main stack _may_ not survive after starting
// tasks
#if 0
    int timer = 10000;
#else
    static int timer = 10000;
#endif

#if 0
    bool EWgreen = true;
#endif

    gpio_set_direction(18, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(19, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(5, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);

    gpio_set_direction(27, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(26, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(25, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);

    ledinfo NSlight;

    NSlight.red = GPIO_NUM_19;
    NSlight.yellow = GPIO_NUM_18;
    NSlight.green = GPIO_NUM_5;
    ledinfo EWlight;

    EWlight.red = GPIO_NUM_27;
    EWlight.yellow = GPIO_NUM_26;
    EWlight.green = GPIO_NUM_25;

    gpio_set_level(NSlight.red, 1);
    gpio_set_level(EWlight.green, 1);
    vTaskDelay(3000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    xTaskCreate(buttonCheck, "BUTTONPRESSCHECK", 150, &timer, 14, NULL);
// xTaskCreate(trafficLights,"TRAFFICLIGHTS",400,&timer,5,NULL);

// NOTE/BUG: buttonCheck task will _not_ be started until vTaskStartScheduler
// is executed
#if 1
// NOTE/FIX: must create a main task (not sure about the parameters for this)
    xTaskCreate(main_task, "main_task", 150, &timer, 14, NULL);
    vTaskStartScheduler();
    while (1);
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: this code will never be executed -- it must go into its own task
// (see main_task above)
#if 0
    while (1) {
        if (EWgreen) {
            toRed(EWlight);
            vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            toGreen(NSlight);
            EWgreen = false;

        }
        else {
            toRed(NSlight);
            vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            toGreen(EWlight);
            EWgreen = true;
        }

        vTaskDelay(timer / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
#endif
}


In the code above, I've used cpp conditionals to denote old vs. new code:
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through unifdef -k

Additional:

Passing a struct by value is slow and consumes stack space.
Better to pass by reference (i.e. a pointer).

So, for example, change the call(s) to (e.g.) toRed from:
toRed(EWlight);

and replace with:
toRed(&EWlight);

The corresponding change to toRed:
void
toRed(const ledinfo *data)
{

    gpio_set_level(data->green, 0);
    gpio_set_level(data->yellow, 1);
    vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    gpio_set_level(data->yellow, 0);
    gpio_set_level(data->red, 1);
}


I would also add that he should use IPC instead of global variables as flags.
